# How to convert arrays of dates from database into m/Y format?

Tags: php, arrays, date, date-formatting

I have arrays of dates that looks like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => 08/03/2017 
    [1] => 09/03/2017 
    [2] => 10/03/2017 
    [3] => 11/03/2017 
    [4] => 12/03/2017 
)
Array(
    [0] => 08/03/2017 
    [1] => 09/03/2017 
    [2] => 10/03/2017 
    [3] => 11/03/2017 
    [4] => 12/03/2017 
    [5] => 01/03/2018 
)
Array(
    [0] => 10/04/2017 
    [1] => 11/04/2017 
    [2] => 12/04/2017 
    [3] => 01/04/2018 
)
```

I need to convert each date of these array to `m/Y` format.

---

I need to convert the `m/d/Y` format to `m/Y` format and I also need to compare it with current date in `m/Y` format.

---

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $result_array[] =  ($row['start_date']);
    $result_array1[] = $row['start_date'];
}
```

---

Is there any way to change the format of date array `$result_array[ ]` to `m/Y`?

---

### Need output like this format(m/Y)

```
Array(
    [0] => 08/2017 
    [1] => 09/2017 
    [2] => 10/2017 
    [3] => 11/2017 
    [4] => 12/2017 
)
Array(
    [0] => 08/2017 
    [1] => 09/2017 
    [2] => 10/2017 
    [3] => 11/2017 
    [4] => 12/2017 
    [5] => 01/2018 
)
Array(
    [0] => 10/2017 
    [1] => 11/2017 
    [2] => 12/2017 
    [3] => 01/2018 
)
```

Comment: `date` and `strotime`.

Comment: I had already tried that, i don't know where i gone wrong

Comment: can you post the code you tried and failed with @Akhil

Comment: @Akhil: there is no attempl using `date` in your edited code.

Comment: sir, i had tried it but it failed

Comment: You can reformat the dates in your query so that your resultset is clean and ready.  You can also compare the dates in sql.  Reasearch the many date functions in sql and search SO. ...And stop using `mysql_` functions they are old news.  Transition to `mysqli` asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this with php, but my advice is to prepare your dates in the SELECT portion of your query.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ffd4e9aa8dd14d695772574113e462a00acffc3))

```
$array1=['08/03/2017','09/03/2017','10/03/2017','11/03/2017','12/03/2017'];
$array2=['08/03/2017','09/03/2017','10/03/2017','11/03/2017','12/03/2017','01/03/2018'];
$array3=['10/04/2017','11/04/2017','12/04/2017','01/04/2018'];

//string function technique:
foreach($array1 as $date){
    $result1[]=substr_replace($date,'',3,3);  // replace {dd/} with an empty string
}
var_export($result1);

echo "\n\n";
// date function technique
foreach($array2 as $date){
    $result2[]=date('m/Y',strtotime($date));
}
var_export($result2);

// mysql function technique *this is the best/cleanest way
$query="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date_fieldname`,'%m/%Y') FROM `your_tablename`";  // now prepared in resultset

echo "\n\n";
// make comparisons
$current_mo_year=date('m/Y');
foreach($array3 as $date){
    $date=substr_replace($date,'',3,3);  // prepare however you like
    echo "Comparison between $current_mo_year & $date: ",($date==$current_mo_year?'same':'different'),"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '08/2017',
  1 => '09/2017',
  2 => '10/2017',
  3 => '11/2017',
  4 => '12/2017',
)

array (
  0 => '08/2017',
  1 => '09/2017',
  2 => '10/2017',
  3 => '11/2017',
  4 => '12/2017',
  5 => '01/2018',
)

Comparison between 11/2017 & 10/2017: different
Comparison between 11/2017 & 11/2017: same
Comparison between 11/2017 & 12/2017: different
Comparison between 11/2017 & 01/2018: different
```